Error in Chainlink Functions source script with EthersJS for Writing to smart contract
After following this example of Chainlink Functions:

I used a basic smart contract like below:

// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity >=0.8.2 <0.9.0;

contract Storage {
    uint256 public number;
    uint256 public counter = 0;

    function store(uint256 num) public {
        number = num;
    }

    function retrieve() public view returns (uint256) {
        return number;
    }

    function increment() external {
        ++counter;
    }
}


Then following the same logic from the example I created this source script:

const ethers = await import("npm:ethers@6.10.0");

const abi = JSON.parse(args[0]);
const CONTRACT_ADDRESS = args[1];

if (!secrets.rpcURL) throw Error("rpcURL environment variable not set.");
if (!secrets.privateKey) throw Error("privateKey environment variable not set.");
const RPC_URL =  secrets.rpcURL;  
const PRIVATE_KEY =  secrets.privateKey;


// Chainlink Functions compatible Ethers JSON RPC provider class
// (this is required for making Ethers RPC calls with Chainlink Functions)
class FunctionsJsonRpcProvider extends ethers.JsonRpcProvider {
  constructor(url) {
    super(url);
    this.url = url;
  }

  async _send(payload) {
    let resp = await fetch(this.url, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      body: JSON.stringify(payload),
    });
    return resp.json();
  }
}

const provider = new FunctionsJsonRpcProvider(RPC_URL);
const wallet = new ethers.Wallet(PRIVATE_KEY);
const signer = wallet.connect(provider); // create ethers signer for signing transactions

const target_sc = new ethers.Contract(CONTRACT_ADDRESS, abi, signer);

// const retrieve_response = await target_sc.retrieve();
const tx = await target_sc.increment();

// return Functions.encodeUint256(retrieve_response);
return Functions.encodeUint256(12233);

This line
const tx = await target_sc.increment();

tries to write on the chain by calling increment() function.
Resulting in errors both in simulation and execution with the following message:
Start simulation...
Simulation result {
  capturedTerminalOutput: '',
  errorString: 'result.filter is not a function'
}
❌ Error during simulation:  result.filter is not a function

... 

✅ Request 0x9f6bdc4f5225e3b1e188512e5cc923a30937e2efe4914a535b78990a8ab52da0 successfully fulfilled. Cost is 0.200015348732910372 LINK.Complete reponse:  {
  requestId: '0x9f6bdc4f5225e3b1e188512e5cc923a30937e2efe4914a535b78990a8ab52da0',
  subscriptionId: 1434,
  totalCostInJuels: 200015348732910372n,
  responseBytesHexstring: '0x',
  errorString: 'TypeError: result.filter is not a function',
  returnDataBytesHexstring: '0x',
  fulfillmentCode: 0
}

❌ Error during the execution:  TypeError: result.filter is not a function

Note: if the line that instead reads from the smart contract is used, then all goes fine
const retrieve_response = await target_sc.retrieve();

So I suspect I am doing something wrong in setting up the Signer in a way that is not Deno and Chainlink DON compatible.
Any suggestions please?

Since the FunctionsJsonRpcProvider class is inheriting ethers.JsonRpcProvider and overriding its _send() function. So, it seems to be supporting only read methods, and failing in case of write methods.
But, still you can  call the write methods by directly calling them using the API endpoints of the jsonrpc 2.0, like eth_chainId, eth_getTransactionCount, eth_sendRawTransaction.
Here's the code to achieve the same:
async function rpcCall(method, params = []) {
    try {

        const body = JSON.stringify({
            jsonrpc: '2.0',
            method: method,
            params: params,
            id: 1
        })
        const response = await fetch(RPC_URL, {
            method: "POST",
            body: body
        });
        return (await response.json()).result;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error executing RPC method:', error);
        throw error;
    }
}

async function getEncodedFunctionData(contract, method, params) {
    const functionABI = contract.interface.getFunction(method);

    // Encode the function call data
    const functionData = contract.interface.encodeFunctionData(functionABI, params);

    return functionData;
}

const method = "increment";

// Get chain ID
const chainId = await rpcCall('eth_chainId');

// Get gas price
const gasPrice = await rpcCall('eth_gasPrice');

// Get sender's nonce
const nonce = await rpcCall('eth_getTransactionCount', [signer.address, 'latest']);

// Encode Function Data
const encodedFunctionData = await getEncodedFunctionData(target_sc, method, []);

const transactionObject = {
    from: signer.address,
    to: CONTRACT_ADDRESS,
    gasPrice: gasPrice,
    nonce: nonce,
    chainId: chainId,
    data: encodedFunctionData
};

transactionObject.gasLimit = await rpcCall('eth_estimateGas', [transactionObject]);

const signedTx = await signer.signTransaction(transactionObject);

// Send raw transaction
const txHash = await rpcCall('eth_sendRawTransaction', [signedTx]);

console.log('Transaction sent. Transaction hash:', txHash);

return Functions.encodeString(txHash);

P.S.: As, now we're returning the transaction hash as the encoded string via Functions.encodeString(txHash), so you've to change all the occurrences of the returnType from ReturnType.int256 to ReturnType.string in the corresponding request.js file.

Many thanks SYED ASAD KAZMI.
This definitely works and has allowed further progress.

You're welcome, @Sokrates. Glad to help!
